# Android: render multiple views in a ScrollView

Tags: scrollview, surfaceview, android-canvas, android

Have a code that renders custom Views and placed on a ScrollView (n by n) with dynamic width per view.

I've been having sluggish performance when running it in Tablet 10.1 but seems ok in Tablet 7.0.

Would there be any improvements if I replaced Views with SurfaceView?

Or would a single SurfaceView with mapped cell work instead? I've found [this](http://www.droidnova.com/create-a-scrollable-map-with-cells-part-iii,737.html) sample project but using this as a guide for the current code seems.. difficult, what with different widths on custom views and the resolution on other devices.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hardware but if you are running on the emulator, it's not accurate. If you are using real devices, try to avoid using custom a lot of custom views because it will be sluggish in a scrollview. Try at least to use standard widgets and move the "custom" parts to another view, it's the simplest, most accesible, and easier to code solution to your problem.
A listview calling another activity would be the fastest and most user friendly approach IMHO.